# Обновление подключений в excel на python

Tags: python, excel, connection

Подскажите как с помощью `win32com.client` или другой библиотеки на python обновить подключения к oracle db в excel? Пробовал `RefreshAll()`, но у меня подключение защищено паролем, поэтому через `RefreshAll()` не получается обновить

```
xlapp = win32com.client("Excel.Application")
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open('filepath')
wb.RefreshAll()
```

Comment: А как  вы в настоящий момент подключаетесь? Не могли бы вы добавить код в вопрос?

Comment: В excel файле сводная таблица подключена к базе oracle. Когда я нажимаю кнопку Обновить все(Refresh All) то выскакивает окно OraOLEDB Logon и там я ввожу пароль и таблица обновляется. Хочу сделать автоматическое обновление на Python и столкнулся с этой проблемой.

Comment: То есть, таблица каким-то образом подключена к БД, но вы не знаете как она подключена. Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Знаю как подключена, знаю строку подключения и sql запрос который берет данные. Знаю логин пароль и название базы в oracle.

Comment: Если знаете, то добавте всё это в виде кода в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

нашла вот такое решение, у меня работает. Обращаю внимание, скрипт актуален для сводных таблиц, которые строятся на данных из Oracle. Для обычных таблиц нужно использовать какой-то другой объект листа Ексель (тут не подскажу, кто знает название объекта - пишите в комментариях, всем будет полезно).

```
import win32com.client 

office = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
wb = office.Workbooks.Open("FPath/FName.xlsx") 

connCount=wb.Connections.Count
for k in range(1,connCount+1):
    wb.Connections(k).OLEDBConnection.Connection = \
        "OLEDB;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YourUserID;password=YourPassword;Data Source=YourDataSource"
    
count = wb.Sheets.Count 
for i in range(count): 
    ws = wb.Worksheets[i+1] 
    pivotCount = ws.PivotTables().Count 
    for j in range(1, pivotCount+1): 
        ws.PivotTables(j).PivotCache().Refresh() 
        print("Worksheet " + ws.Name + " updated")  

for k in range(1,connCount+1):
    wb.Connections(k).OLEDBConnection.SavePassword = False
  
office.Save()
wb.Close()
office.Quit()
```